# Entity Framework Code First - two Foreign Keys from same table not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

I have two foreign Keys from same table defined like this:

```
public class OfferTemplate {    ...
 [ForeignKey("CompanyAgentBuyer_CompanyAgentID")]
 [InverseProperty("OfferTemplatesAsBuyer")]
 public virtual CompanyAgent CompanyAgentBuyer { get; set; }

 [ForeignKey("CompanyAgentBroker_CompanyAgentID")]
 [InverseProperty("OfferTemplatesAsBroker")]
 public virtual CompanyAgent CompanyAgentBroker { get; set; }

 public int CompanyAgentBuyer_CompanyAgentID { get; set; }
 public int? CompanyAgentBroker_CompanyAgentID { get; set; }
 ...
}
```

On the model I got this setup:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<OfferTemplate>()
            .HasRequired(ca => ca.CompanyAgentBuyer)
            .WithMany(t => t.OfferTemplatesAsBuyer)
            .HasForeignKey(ca => ca.CompanyAgentBuyer_CompanyAgentID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<OfferTemplate>()
           .HasOptional(ca => ca.CompanyAgentBroker)
           .WithMany(t => t.OfferTemplatesAsBroker)
           .HasForeignKey(ca => ca.CompanyAgentBroker_CompanyAgentID)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

So far everything works, except when I do the query:

```
var templates = from user in context.UsersInformation
                            from cTemplate in context.OfferTemplates
                            where user.User.Equals(userID) && cTemplate.Company == user.Company
                            select cTemplate;

var x = templates.FirstOrDefault().CompanyAgentBuyer;
```

While the ID properties (CompanyAgentBuyer_CompanyAgentID & CompanyAgentBroker_CompanyAgentID) are being populated correctly the instance (like in this case x) is not being populated. I tried using Include method but it didn't work either. Any ideas what I am missing?

Comment: where do you do the include? since you do a join and projection query, includes will be destroyed if not done after query regrouping.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro thank you. No, I am not using the Include right now.

Answer (score 0):

I end up changing the model to this:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyAgent>()
            .HasMany(e => e.OfferTemplatesAsBroker)
            .WithOptional(e => e.CompanyAgentBroker)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.CompanyAgentBroker_CompanyAgentID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyAgent>()
            .HasMany(e => e.OfferTemplatesAsBuyer)
            .WithRequired(e => e.CompanyAgentBuyer)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.CompanyAgentBuyer_CompanyAgentID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

now it is working.